# Two methods Post in a form

Tags: laravel

I have an external paiement application service who take care about the paiements from my shopping application .

I have a form method Post to the service to send the data and the service valide the payment transaction .

```
 <form method="POST" action="https://paiement.systempay.fr/vads-payment/">
...
<input type="submit" name="payer" value="Payer"/></form>
</form>
```

I would like to post also a request method from my payment controller to update my items who was paid

here my controller wish i would like to be run when the user click on "payer" also

```
public function postCheckoutCreditCard(Request $request)
    {
        if(!Session::has('Cart')){

            return view('shop.panier');
        }
        $oldCart = Session::get('Cart') ;
        $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
        $items = $cart->items;

        if(Input::get('payer')) {

            // on inject le nouveau statut de la licence
            foreach ($items as $item) {

                $item['item']->statut_licence_id = LicenceStatut::where('id', '4')->firstOrFail()->id;
                $item['item']->valid_licence_id = LicenceValid::where('id', '1')->firstOrFail()->id;
                $item['item']->save();

            }

            $order = new Order;
            $prefix = 'F';
            $date = Carbon::now();
            $saison = Saison::where('dt_deb', '<', $date)->where('dt_fin', '>', $date)->value('lb_saison');
            $saison_deb = substr($saison, 2, 2);
            $saison_fin = substr($saison, -2);
            $num_facture_exist = true;
            while ($num_facture_exist) {
                $num_facture = $prefix . $saison_deb . $saison_fin . substr(uniqid(rand(), true), 4, 4);
                if (!Order::where('num_facture', '=', $num_facture)->exists()) {
                    $order->num_facture = $num_facture;
                    $num_facture_exist = false;
                }
            }
            $order->structure_id = Structure::where(['id' => Auth::user()->structure->id])->firstOrFail()->id;
            $order->cart = serialize($cart);
            $order->date_achat = Carbon::now();
            $order->payment_method = 'Carte de Crédit';
            $order->etat_paiement = 'Facture Réglée';

            $order->save();

            Auth::user()->notify(new InvoicePaid($order));

            $federation = Structure::where('id', '1')->first();
            Mail::to($federation->adresse_email_structure)->send(new NouvelleCommande($order));

            Session::forget('Cart');

            return redirect('home')->with('status', "Votre paiement à été effectué avec sucess , votre numéro de facture : . $order->num_facture est disponible dans la rubrique Mes cotisation ");
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure how to do this . someone could help me ? thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that? What if the payment to the external service fails? Usually these services support getting a callback URL to post to when done processing the request.

Comment: yes it's exactly it's what i will do ! i will ask them . but i'm sure then have that

Comment: there is a service in the external application who redirect to an url when the payement is accepted do you think if i put the url to acces to the method public function postCheckoutCreditCard(Request $request) it will work ?

Comment: That would probably work but you need to check if the redirect is done via "POST" or "GET" and also what parameters are included in the request and adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: thanks a lot i will check

Answer (score 0):

I would change the form action to your Controller and then use Guzzle to call the external route. Check here about Guzzle (http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#post-form-requests).

Call something like this in your Controller:

```
$response = $client->request('POST', 'https://paiement.systempay.fr/vads-payment/', [
    'form_params' => [
        'field_name' => 'abc',
    ]
]);
```

Then check the response and return something based on it.